# Goldbach conjecture reformulation

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problems, arithmetic-progression

As thought, the question below is a reformulation of the goldbach conjecture.

$ S = \{K - ap \mid a \geq 3, p \text{ is prime} < K/2  \} $, where $ a $ is an odd integer greater than or equal to 3, and $ p $ is a prime number $ K/2 $,

A set $ S $ can be visualized :

\begin{bmatrix}
K - 3p_1 & K - 5p_1 & K - 7p_1 & K - 9p_1 & \ldots \\
K - 3p_2 & K - 5p_2 & K - 7p_2 & K - 9p_2 & \ldots \\
K - 3p_3 & K - 5p_3 & K - 7p_3 & K - 9p_3 & \ldots \\
K - 3p_n & K - 5p_n & K - 7p_n & K - 9p_n & \ldots \\
\end{bmatrix}

Does there exist an even number $ K $ such that every prime in the range $ [K/2, K] $ can be expressed as member of $ S $?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are asking whether such a $K$ exists, or whether you are asking whether every even $K$ has this property.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is whether such a $ K $ exists.

Comment: Did you do any searching? Do you have a lower bound on $K$? (Note that $K$ has to have at least 8 composite numbers preceding it, so $K=122$ is an immediate lower bound, and there are only a handful of sufficiently large gaps for the next several hundred numbers, so it wouldn't be surprising if the minimal $K$ is fairly large.)

Comment: There is particular reason I have not done any searching and that is because I believe this question can be reformulated as the goldbach conjecture. (I think this is quite trivial to show) In fact I came up with this question pondering the Goldbach Conjecture.  Ie, if goldbach were false then a K would exist for which a Set S encompasses the primes Q.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is equivalent to a notorious open problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K$ exists with the required property if and only if the Goldbach conjecture is false.

Assume first that $K$ has the property in the original post. Then $K\geq 6$, and for every prime $q\in[K/2,K]$, the odd number $K-q$ is composite (i.e. it factors as $ap$ with $a\geq 3$ odd and $p\leq K/2$ a prime). That is, the equation $K=q+q'$ has no solution in prime numbers $q'\leq q$, and the Goldbach conjecture is false.

Assume now that the Goldbach conjecture is false. Then there exists an even $K\geq 6$ such that the equation $K=q+q'$ has no solution in prime numbers $q'\leq q$. That is, for every prime $q\in[K/2,K]$, the odd number $K-q$ is composite (i.e. it factors as $ap$ with $a\geq 3$ odd and $p\leq K/2$ a prime). Hence $K$ has the property in the original post.

Comment: Thanks. I posed this question as a result of thinking about the Goldbach Conjecture